# Cannot instance an JEqualizer in android

Tags: android, delphi, process, firemonkey, record

In FMX Delphi 11 I'm recording audio to process it.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
  FChannelConfig:= TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
  FAudioFormat  := TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
  FTailleBufferBytes := TJAudioRecord.JavaClass.getMinBufferSize(FSampleRate, FChannelConfig, FAudioFormat); 

  // VOICE_RECOGNITION
  AUDIO_SOURCE:= TJMediaRecorder_AudioSource.JavaClass.VOICE_RECOGNITION ;

  //UNPROCESSED Added in API 24
  if (TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.SDK_INT >= 24) then
  begin
    FAudioManager:= TJAudioManager.Wrap((TAndroidHelper.Activity.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.AUDIO_SERVICE) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    AudioMngrProp:= FAudioManager.getProperty(TJAudioManager.JavaClass.PROPERTY_SUPPORT_AUDIO_SOURCE_UNPROCESSED) ;
    if (Boolean.Parse(JStringToString(AudioMngrProp))) then
    begin
      AUDIO_SOURCE:= TJMediaRecorder_AudioSource.JavaClass.UNPROCESSED ;
    end;
  end;

  // Init FAudioRecord
  FAudioRecord := TJAudioRecord.JavaClass.init(AUDIO_SOURCE, FSampleRate, FChannelConfig, FAudioFormat, FTailleBufferBytes);

  // Start recording
  FAudioRecord.StartRecording;
```

In some Android devices, I have bad levels on a different ways: 10 times greater, 4 times lower, levels reduction on low frequencies, ... So I decided to get all informations about audio effects being used by Android and try to disable it in my application. Doing this I hope to fix my errors levels in my app.

Both following instances sent me an exception when creating equalizer object:

```
var sessionID:= FAudioRecord.getAudioSessionId() ;
var FEqualizer := TJEqualizer.JavaClass.init(0, sessionID);
//var FEqualizer := TJEqualizer.JavaClass.init(0, (TAndroidHelper.Activity.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.AUDIO_SERVICE) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID) ;
```

> Cannot initialize effect engine for type xxxx Error: -3

SessionID is not null.

I thought it was a permission problem. In the manifest, I have to add the MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

This permission don't need to be request at runtime.

Comment: What value is `sessionID` when creating the `Equalizer`? By the way, I just used `Equalizer` as an example in your previous question. Also, the `init` method for `TJAudioRecord` returns a `JAudioRecord` - you should not need to typecast it

Comment: sessionID is not null and equals to 41 the first time. It is incrementing by 8 when instancing a new RecordAudio object. I have same error (Cannot initialize effect engine for type xxxx Error: -3) with other AudioEffect (Reverb).

Comment: [This appears to imply that effects are not available](https://source.android.com/docs/core/audio/implement-pre-processing) when using VOICE_RECOGNITION. I suggest trying VOICE_COMMUNICATION. Other searches suggest that any low-latency source does not support effects, so you might want to discover which of those that applies to.

Comment: I tried all audio source types. I tought UNPROCESSED was the better one but the levels issues are exiting with that source. VOICE_COMMUNICATION is not using my USB plugged mic but the internal mic. Moreover I still have the Equalizer error initialization with VOICE_COMMUNICATION audio source.

Comment: I maybe have find something about https://source.android.com/docs/core/audio/implement-pre-processing?hl=en but I don't know how to add system file in Android (it seems that I cannot add file in system). My device has AES and NS preprocess option for audio source VOICE_COMMUNICATION.

Comment: audio_effects.xml applies to device vendors, not developers. Does the `MIC` audio source use the plugged in mic? It might also help to update your question if the code has any significant changes

Comment: Thanks Dave. Yes, the audio source used the plugged mic. I got the name of the plugged mic with `FAudioRecord.getRoutedDevice.getProductName` function. Unfortunately, the code is practically the same because I haven't found any solutions that would improve my acquisition.

Comment: The code in the question uses `VOICE_RECOGNITION`, and you said you cannot create effects using it.

Comment: Sorry David I don't understand. `AUDIO_SOURCE` is initialized with `VOICE_RECOGNITION` but then takes on the value `UNPROCESSED` because I have API level greater than 24.

Comment: How can it "take on the value `UNPROCESSED`"? It's a constant. This part of the code: `AUDIO_SOURCE:= TJMediaRecorder_AudioSource.JavaClass.VOICE_RECOGNITION`. Regardless, if you have changed *any* part of your code, update the question

Comment: I probably have some understandings because of translations... My variable `AUDIO_SOURCE` is equal to `UNPROCESSED` because I have API level greater than 24. The main problem is that I cannot initialize an `TJEqualizer` with `UNPROCESSED`. Despite tests the code still remains the same.